# Hibernate cannot save inherited object

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I have two entities - superclass and its child:

Superclass (but not abstract):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table1")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class table1 implements Serializable {
   @Id
   String id;
}
```

Subclass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table2")
public class table2 extends table1 {
   String somefield;
}
```

Both tables are created fine during start.

But when i trying to save subclass's object:

```
table2 obj = new table2();
dbSession.save(obj);
```

I get an error: `org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session`

How to solve this? I only need to extend second class from the first and use this as different tables.

I also tried `.merge()` method, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have String id, are you sure that it is not empty or not exist in your db when you persist object?

Try this:

```
table2 obj = new table2();
obj.setId("new unique id")
dbSession.save(obj);
```